# Laravel - Authentication trait error exception

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

I am doing an ajax login in my `Laravel` application. It worked fine on my local environment, but I moved the site to Production, on login I see this exception

> ErrorException in User.php line 29: Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User
>   and Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable define the same property
>   ($rememberTokenName) in the composition of App\User. This might be
>   incompatible, to improve maintainability consider using accessor
>   methods in traits instead. Class was composed

My User model is as

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable, \Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'hospital_id', 'census_id', 'employee_id'
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User` already uses use `Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable`, so you basically applying the trait twice which causes that error.

Here's the code to Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User.php

```
<?php

namespace Illuminate\Foundation\Auth;

use Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\CanResetPassword;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Access\Authorizable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable as AuthenticatableContract;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Access\Authorizable as AuthorizableContract;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\CanResetPassword as CanResetPasswordContract;

class User extends Model implements
    AuthenticatableContract,
    AuthorizableContract,
    CanResetPasswordContract
{
    use Authenticatable, Authorizable, CanResetPassword;
}
```

Also a side suggestion rename your alias bit `as Authenticable` maybe to something more clear like `AuthUser` / `BaseUser` so it's clear you are extending a User class.

Comment: You mean I should remove this `\Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable`

Comment: Right, it's already being used in the parent class (see the line with  `use Authenticatable`)